# Does Scribe support 3-legged OAuth?

Tags: java, scribe

Does [the Scribe OAuth library](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java) (written in Java) support 3-legged [OAuth](http://hueniverse.com/oauth/)?

Here someone says it's for 2-legged only:
[How do I use OAuth within my GWT application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966856/how-do-i-use-oauth-within-my-gwt-application)

> [...] this is because scribe is for 2-legged-auth [...]

But in a code snippet on this blog post:
[Two-Legged OAuth in Java (using Scribe) to Access SimpleGeo](http://devlog.bafford.us/two-legged-oauth-in-java-using-scribe-to-acce)
I read:

> [...] for 3-legged you would need to request the authorization token [...]

which gives me the impression 3-legged OAuth is possible, albeit I don't know how easy or hard it would be. (I'm new to OAuth.)

(What is 3-legged OAuth? Search for "3-legged", [here](http://hueniverse.com/2008/10/beginners-guide-to-oauth-part-iii-security-architecture/).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, scribe does support 3-legged OAuth. You can try its examples that do exactly the 3-legged OAuth. You do need to be familiar with Maven to build and run tests easily. I wrote something about it when I was testing scribe against Yahoo's contact data at http://agilesc.barryku.com/?p=175.