# Javascript OAuth and Opera Link

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, oauth, opera

I am writing a Chrome extension that synchronizes with Opera Link, but I keep struggling with OAuth. I have tried three different OAuth libraries, but they don't work.

These libraries are:

- http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/javascript/
- https://github.com/bytespider/jsoauth
- http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tut_oauth.html

All of them can't fetch client tokens. I have only read-only access when I use the first and insert the tokens.

"javascript oauth opera link" doesn't give results in Google.

(EDIT:) My question is: has anyone had luck in using Opera Link in pure JavaScript, or does anyone know what the problem is?

EDIT2: this doesn't work for me: [application that uses OAuth and javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221371/application-that-uses-oauth-and-javascript). I can use it if I get 'token' and 'tokenSecret' with the Python API debugger, but only read-only. I can't for example add new bookmarks.

Comment: You didn't explain why you felt any of the libraries didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just put my Opera Link JavaScript library up at https://github.com/ChaosinaCan/OperaLink.js. (It's the one emanchado linked to)

I've only tested some of the bookmark functions so far, so please tell me if anything doesn't work.

Comment: It worked. I have forked the repository and modified it a bit to get i t work on Google Chrome. Maybe you can merge that in your code? And again, thanks for the hard work you put in this piece of code!

Comment: Now that I see I can leave comments: I've merged your changes. I'll get to writing some proper tests once I'm finished writing an update to one of my Opera extensions.

Answer (score 1):

Hey there!
The other day I made an Opera extension work with the Opera Link API: https://github.com/emanchado/Javascript-OAuth-experiments

Have a look at both the extension code itself, and https://github.com/emanchado/Javascript-OAuth-experiments/blob/master/oauthtest.js (also oauthtestget.js for a GET request example).

Comment: Oh really thanks! I haven't got time at the moment, but I will look at it soon. It seems to be pretty easy to use...

Comment: And I just found this gem:

http://my.opera.com/spadija/blog/2011/04/25/opera-link-library-preview?cid=59705952

I haven't used it or looked at the code yet, but it seems pretty nice.

Answer (score 0):

The [Opera Link API introduction](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/introducing-the-opera-link-api/) article gives information and specifically a [debugger python script](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/introducing-the-opera-link-api/linkapidebugger.zip). I might help to understand your code issues.

It would help also if you could provide a bit of code.

Comment: I have tried the debugger python script, that one works. But I want to make it work in pure JavaScript (Python can't be executed inside chrome extensions).

Comment: hmm I see. I do not know any good Javascript OAuth lib, but I'm asking around.

Comment: People recommends [oauth.js](http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/javascript/oauth.js) that you have used it seems.