# How do I secure REST calls I am making in-app?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, rest, restful-authentication, tipfy

I have an application that has a "private" REST API; I use RESTful URLs when making Ajax calls from my own webpages. However, this is unsecure, and anyone could make those same calls if they knew the URL patterns.

**What's the best (or standard) way to secure these calls?** Is it worth looking at something like OAuth now if I intend to release an API in the future, or am I mixing two separate strategies together?

I am using Google App Engine for Python and Tipfy.

Comment: Thank you, everyone, for your input. I selected OAuth because it is standard, will serve me now, and in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Definitely take a look at [OAuth](http://oauth.net/)

It is quickly becoming the "de-facto" standard for securing REST APIs and a lot of big companies are using it, including [Google](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth.html), [Twitter](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/oauth_faq) and [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) just to name a few.

For Python on GAE you have two options:

The most straightforward way (IMHO) is using David Larlet's library for [OAuth Support in Django](http://code.welldev.org/django-oauth/wiki/Home) available on BitBucket.

But since you're not using Django, maybe you want to take a look at the [python-oauth2](https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2) library that's available on GitHub, and is considered the most up-to-date and unit-tested implementation of OAuth for Python 2.4+.

Either way I think you'd be much better using OAuth than rolling your own service security solution.

Comment: If you're going to use OAuth, you should probably use OAuth 2.0 http://wiki.oauth.net/w/page/25236487/OAuth-2 -- https://github.com/progrium/oauth2-appengine

Comment: Why would you use OAuth from your own webpage to your own "private" REST API?

Comment: @Erick the webpage is the client and the server is the resource provider.

Answer (score 4):

Securing a javascript client is nearly impossible; at the server, you have no fool-proof way to differentiate between a human using a web browser and a well-crafted script.

SSL encrypts data over the wire but decrypts at the edges, so that's no help. It prevents man-in-the-middle attacks, but does nothing to verify the legitimacy of the original client.

OAuth is good for securing requests between two servers, but for a Javascript client, it doesn't really help: anyone reading your javascript code can find your consumer key/secret, and then they can forge signed requests.

Some things you can do to *mitigate* API scraping:

- Generate short-lived session cookies when someone visits your website. Require a valid session cookie to invoke the REST API.
- Generate short-lived request tokens and include them in your website HTML; require a valid request token inside each API request.
- Require users of your website to log in (Google Accounts / OpenID); check auth cookie before handling API requests.
- Rate-limit API requests. If you see too many requests from one client in a short time frame, block them.

Answer (score 1):

OAuth would be overkill in your current scenario ([potentially insecure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221371/application-that-uses-oauth-and-javascript)), in that it's designed to authorize a third party service to have access to resources on behave of the user.

#### Securing AJAX request via an authorized user

AFAICT, you are in control of the client, resources and authentication; so you only need to secure access to the URL's and possibly the communication between client and server via SSL [2].

So, use Tipfy's [auth extension](http://www.tipfy.org/wiki/extensions/auth/) to secure your URLs:

```
from tipfy import RequestHandler, Response
from tipfy.ext.auth import AppEngineAuthMixin, user_required

class MyHandler(RequestHandler, AppEngineAuthMixin):
    @user_required
    def get(self, **kwargs):
        return Response('Only logged in users can see this page.')
```

#### Securing AJAX request without an authorized user

If a user is unknown, then one could apply CSRF preventions to help protect the REST service from being called from an "unauthorized" client.  Tipfy has this built-in to it's [WTForms extension](http://www.tipfy.org/wiki/extensions/wtforms), but it's not AJAX.  Instead, the [session extension](http://www.tipfy.org/wiki/extensions/session) could be used to apply an "authenticity_token" to all calls, that needs to be verified on the server.

Comment: Thanks, Erick. The only problem is I need to use Ajax even if someone is not logged in. Is there another decorator from Tipfy that fulfills this purpose?

Comment: @Wraith, how will identify a valid user from an invalid one?

Comment: Anyone can use basic features of the site, but some are restricted. Using the decorator is clear-cut when a valid, logged-in user is needed, but I still use Ajax for anonymous users.

Comment: The only thing I can think of, is to use the "secret_key" feature in tipfy's session extension to create some sort of hash verification to ensure that the calls are coming from your AJAX app.