# oAuth - HTML/CSS/JS + REST APIs without MVC. C# .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, oauth

I want to create a responsive website that will work in all devices. Front end is HTML/CSS/JS and I am going to create bunch of APIs which will interact with database and do all the business logic and data fetch required.

I want to implement oAuth. oAuth for the front end's communication with my REST APIs. Why? I potentially see a need for more external parties to access my REST APIs in future.

How can I do this without MVC or seesion. Without MVC I suppose I might end up storing the site key, secret and auth id in cookie. How dangerous is it? Please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Am just thinking loud. I do not want to choose MVC/HTTPSession path without thinking. Can I store key, secret etc in browser memory or something in a secure way?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I do this without MVC or seesion

since you don't want to use a server side MVC as a middle layer between your client side and your API endpoints, you're going to be building your application in javascript. in that case *do* use an MV* framework to structure your data / events relationships to the API and page.

In terms of using oAuth, what you're going to need to do is use or write a javascript library for oAuth, and there are plenty of discussions about that, here's one: [application that uses OAuth and javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221371/application-that-uses-oauth-and-javascript).

Because you wont be using a middle layer, you won't be touching session either, and typically that means you're going to make some special key and hash it and store it as a cookie, thus giving every client a *stateless* connection to the API.

> How dangerous is it?

it is common practice, but you must salt and hash that key, otherwise the key will be not secure enough.

Comment: Thanks Kristian. _"it is common practice, but you must salt and hash that key, otherwise the key will be not secure enough."_ **Can you give me some reference?**