# Laravel 5.4 passport password grant tokens

Tags: laravel-5.4

I am learning laravel 5.4 api authorization chapter. I have a question about password grant tokens. The doc said this is for my other first-party clients. And now I build an api service, it uses OAuth2. Now I want to build my front end website, and I want to use password grant tokens. So in my understanding, like login, I will send an ajax request including username,password,grant_type,client_id,client_secret,scope to `/oauth/tokens` to get access token. Should I just put client secret in my js code directly? Because if not, I don't know where to store my client secret, someone can help me? Thanks.

Comment: I think this question should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24724238/how-do-client-side-js-libraries-for-oauth2-maintain-secure-authentication

Answer (score 0):

Laravel Passport requires understanding about OAuth so I think it better to understand it first before using passport.

> So in my understanding, like login, I will send an ajax request
>   including username,password,grant_type,client_id,client_secret,scope
>   to /oauth/tokens to get access token

Please take a look at this. [image]

> Should I just put client secret in my js code directly

Yes. To explain briefly, once you installed laravel passport. It will generate tables in your database, you will use `oauth_clients` table to store the data for clients.

For simple authentication like getting information, you only need `oauth_clients.id`, `oauth_clients.secret` and `oauth_clients.redirect` data. You can create new data by using `php artisan passport:client`

I recommend to try it and you will encounter problems soon that can easily be fixed. Goodluck

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport

Comment: Please explain the reasoning for including client secret in front-end javascript code, as every other article / book I have read strongly advises against this for security reasons.

Comment: In general, you should NOT include the client secret, not even the client id, in any code (or binaries that can be decompiled) that is delivered to your users/customers/etc.